# Context before and after a word (xslt)

Tags: xslt

```
<block>
   <p>(...) nogen Forundring, med dyb Bedrøvelse, men <seg>end</seg> dybere Rolighed, læsde jeg Baggesens Svar til mig i Skilderiet No. 9 (...)</p>
</block>
```

I am all new when it comes to xslt. How do I pick the context, say three words before and after, the content tagged with the element ? I have been trying whit string-before and string-after but whit no success at all.

The result should look like this:

```
word: end

context: dyb Bedrøvelse, men end dybere Rolighed, læsde
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 or are you limited to 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not know whether your XSLT processor supports XSLT 2.0, but since I wrote an answer before realizing that:

The reason the version is important is that the solution below uses a function that is available only in XSLT 2.0, namely `tokenize()`. Saying things like "selecting three words before and after" only make sense if you *tokenize* the strings you want to process in this fashion. Before tokenization, the concept of "words" is unknown to the XSLT processor.

**Stylesheet**

**EDIT**: As a response to your comment, I have slightly adapted the code to work with several `seg` elements. Of course, this introduces other difficulties that you need to deal with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="seg">
      <xsl:text>word: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#x0a;context: </xsl:text>

      <xsl:variable name="tok-before" select="tokenize(normalize-space(string-join(preceding::text(),'')),' ')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="tok-after" select="tokenize(normalize-space(string-join(following::text(),'')),' ')"/>

      <xsl:value-of select="subsequence($tok-before,count($tok-before) -2)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',.,' ')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="subsequence($tok-after,1,3)"/>
      <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
word: end
context: med dyb Bedrøvelse, men end dybere Rolighed, læsde
```

---

You can try and manipulate this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzPZ).

Comment: Tokenizing is available in XSLT 1.0 too, either as an extension function or as a named template. However, implementing *the concept of "words"* requires more than tokenization - since words are not always separated by spaces (or spaces alone). The missing part is the concept of *punctuation characters* - which is available only in XSLT 2.0 through regex.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know that tokenization in XSLT 1.0 is possible and that tokenization with whitespace as the only separator does not work too well. I would extend my answer with more detail - if the question was also a detailed one. But then, implementing the concept of words requires more than whitespace and punctuation characters, even then the tokenization is far from perfect. But don't you think that's too much detail given the circumstances?

Comment: Thank you. A context of three word before and after the <seg>-element is not essential. 20 or 40 characters before and after would be fine too. I have a supplementary question. If there is more than one <seg>, what do I do? <block>
   <p>(...) nogen Forundring, med <seg>dyb</seg> Bedrøvelse, men <seg>end</seg> dybere Rolighed, læsde jeg Baggesens Svar til mig i Skilderiet No. 9 (...)</p>
</block>

KSR

Comment: @Mathias Müller. The reason I ask again is because I do not get the template to work with more than one <seg>. I am new to XSLT. I am sorry if my question is not detailed enough og to stupid. I would like to say that I understand the answer, but unfortunately it is not the case.

Comment: @KSR I have updated the XSLT code again. Can you try another time? You can simply click on this [link](http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzPZ). Having multiple `seg` introduces other problems, because a `seg` element could obstruct the context of another `seg`.