# XSLT first occurrence of element based on a particular value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a xml file as below , Expected output should have only the  elements based on the first occurance of recordNumber
Xml File  is as below :-

```
      <catalog>
<cd>
      <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <year>1985</year>
              <recordNumber>100</recordNumber>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <year>1988</year>
              <recordNumber>101</recordNumber>

</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <year>1982</year>
              <recordNumber>102</recordNumber>

</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <year>1990</year>
              <recordNumber>100</recordNumber>

</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <year>1997</year>
              <recordNumber>100</recordNumber>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <year>1998</year>
              <recordNumber>101</recordNumber>
</cd>
```

Expected Output :-Expected output should have only the  elements based on the first occurance of recordNumber

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <year>1985</year>
              <recordNumber>100</recordNumber>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <year>1988</year>
              <recordNumber>101</recordNumber>

</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <year>1982</year>
              <recordNumber>102</recordNumber>

</cd>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the XSLT file. We like to help, but we need to see what you have done so far and where it is going wrong (this is not a site for asking others to do the programming for you, it is a Q&A site). Please update your question. See also [ask].

Comment: You have tagged your question as both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. They are meant to be mutually exclusive. Please pick one of these, as the answers are significantly different between the two. I would also suggest you do a search, as this (grouping) is one of the most often asked questions here.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use XSLT 2.0 grouping:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="cd" group-by="recordNumber">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: I tried this solution , but the for-each-group is not supported. I am using xalan parser and the xsl displays its version="2.0".

Comment: Xalan does not support XSLT 2.0. If you want to use XSLT 2.0 in a Java environment, use Saxon.

Answer (score 0):

Although this search is pretty intensive it does the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd[count(preceding-sibling::cd[recordNumber = current()/recordNumber]) > 0]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I copied the input xml and the xsl you provided in the w3schools editor.Its not working . Also looks like it would be a performance hit.

Comment: Use a better XSLT processor than w3schools, XSLT would work. As mentioned this solution is pretty intensive and performance wise not the best solution. For performance use the XSLT 2.0 solution from Michael Kay

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the input XML you have shown is not well-formed. It lacks a closing `</catalog>` tag.

Your requirement is a quite trivial one. It can be solved with two templates, one performing an *identity transformation*, the other keeps `cd` elements from being sent to the output if they are preceded by another `cd` element with an identical `recordNumber` element.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="cd[preceding::cd[recordNumber = current()/recordNumber]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
   <cd>
      <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      <year>1985</year>
      <recordNumber>100</recordNumber>
   </cd>
   <cd>
      <title>Hide your heart</title>
      <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
      <year>1988</year>
      <recordNumber>101</recordNumber>
   </cd>
   <cd>
      <title>Greatest Hits</title>
      <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
      <year>1982</year>
      <recordNumber>102</recordNumber>
   </cd>
</catalog>
```

---

By the way:

- As @michael.hor257k has noted, this solution will perform badly on big input XML documents, because of the number of comparisons that have to be made. A more scalable solution would use a grouping mechanism (like `for-each-group` in XSLT 2.0).
- never trust the output of anything on www.w3schools.com. Rely on trustworthy sources, like the W3C.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have not claimed it is. It is just that the question here does not seem to demonstrate any research effort. I am willing to invest more time and provide a performant, scalable answer (in addition to giving the correct result) only for questions that e.g. do make an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: I didn't say you claimed it was. But it needs to be added that it isn't. -- P.S. This is not about you, and I don't see why you need to defend yourself; no one is attacking you. I thought I should add this in view of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377797/context-before-and-after-a-word-xslt/25383802?noredirect=1#comment39596151_25383802

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know Michael ;) I felt I had to explain why I did not provide a better answer in the first place. I have already edited my answer to add a note on performance.